# Run-time error '1004' Application-definded or object-defined error. VBA EXCEL

Tags: vba, excel

here's what my macro does. It finds a string given a large excel file and goes to that column. At that point, it finds a user inputted string and copies all results onto the column next to it. I started learning VBA yesterday, so any help is appreciated.

here's where it gets the error
`While InStr(UCase(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, j)), UCase("request")) = 0`

Here's my complete macro so far.

```
    Sub FineMe()

Dim i, j As Long
Dim count, test As Integer

userinput = InputBox("Enter String", Search, "Collect user input")
Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 28

 While InStr(UCase(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, j)), UCase("request")) = 0
    j = j + 1

    Wend

EndRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.count, j).End(xlUp).Row
count = 1
    For i = 1 To EndRow
        test = InStr(UCase(Cells(i, j)), UCase(userinput))
            If test > 0 Then
            Cells(count, j + 1).Value = Cells(i, j).Value

            count = count + 1

            End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated. THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `j = 1` before `While`, because after declaration `Dim i, j As Long` we have `j` equals to `0` and `Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 0)` triggers an error (we haven't `Cells(1,0)`)

```
Sub FineMe()

    Dim i, j As Long
    Dim count, test As Integer

    userinput = InputBox("Enter String", Search, "Collect user input")
    Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 28

    j = 1
    While InStr(UCase(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, j)), UCase("request")) = 0
        j = j + 1
    Wend

    EndRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.count, j).End(xlUp).Row
    count = 1
    For i = 1 To EndRow
        test = InStr(UCase(Cells(i, j)), UCase(userinput))
            If test > 0 Then
            Cells(count, j + 1).Value = Cells(i, j).Value

            count = count + 1

            End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

BTW, in line `Dim i, j As Long` only `j` is `Long`, but `i` is `Variant`. You should use `Dim i As Long, j As Long` instead. The same thing with `Dim count, test As Integer` - you should declare it as follows: `Dim count As Integer, test As Integer`

Answer (score 0):

i think Instr(1, what you wrote. 
clic Instr in VB editor, and press F1